# Phone number validating in php

Tags: php

I would like to "validate" my posted phone number. I don't really care about the format, i just want to use only numbers and some chars.
I tried this code, but if i type at least one number to my string then string will be valid. (for ex.: asdafadas-1asd will be valid)
 How to fix this?

```
$phonebool=true;
       if (!(strcspn($_POST['phone'], '0123456789-/ ') != strlen($_POST['phone']) )){
           $_SESSION['phone_err']='Only numbers and -/';
           $phonebool=false;
       }
```

thank you.

Comment: If you are not concerned of the dashes, than simply use `is_numeric()`

Comment: Just be aware that phone number formats vary between countries, states, carriers, etc. and the only common denominator is probably that it's a series of numbers.

Comment: is numeric contain "-" and "/" ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a regular expression instead, something like:

```
/^[0-9\/-]+$/
```

Otherwise have a look at libphonenumber - it seems that a php port exists: https://github.com/davideme/libphonenumber-for-PHP

Examples:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[0-9\/-]+$/', 'asdafadas-1asd'));
=> int(0)

var_dump(preg_match('/^[0-9\/-]+$/', '12/34-56'));
=> int(1)
```

Comment: A tip on how to implement the regular expression within his code would be nice... :-)

Comment: You can use preg_match it returns 1 if the string matches the patern, 0 otherwise (or FALSE if there was en error)

Comment: Examples like that should be incorporated and formatted in the answer, so it's easier to read :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try This .

```
if(ereg("^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$", $number) ) {
    echo "works";
} else {
    $errmsg = 'Please enter your valid phone number';
}
```

Comment: this works, but only for numbers formatted `xxx-xxx-xxxx`  you could just change the regular expression to something like `"[0-9/-]+"` and use it.

Comment: I would add a space in that character set too, and possibly parenthesis, i.e. `[ )(0-9/-]`

Comment: don't use `ereg()` -- it is deprecated. Use `preg_match()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Working code

```
if (!(preg_match("([0-9-]+)", $_POST['phone']) != strlen($_POST['phone']) )){
    $_SESSION['phone_err']='Only numbers and -/';
    $phonebool=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one recommendation: use javascript/jquery to validate your forms, so the users can correct right away before submit.

Comment: no mention of client-side operations in the initial question.  Also; always good to validate server-side as well as client-side.

Comment: yeah, you didn't mention your previous validations at all. Nevermind, you could test with preg_match instead of `strcspn`. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$phonebool=true;
if (!(preg_match("([0-9-]+)", $_POST['phone']) != strlen($_POST['phone']) )){
    $_SESSION['phone_err']='Only numbers and -/';
    $phonebool=false;
}
```